# ERROR when run start-dfs.sh in Hadoop-3.2.0

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I meet some problems in the configuration of Hadoop3.2.1 for YARN learning. And I found that there are two different conditions in user root and user host1 when I run the sbin/start-all.sh. Can you tell me how to solve it and whether it has connection with the SSH? Thank you very much.

In Root:

```
root@host1-virtual-machine:/home/host1/usr/hadoop-3.2.1# sbin/start-all.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs namenode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_NAMENODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
Starting datanodes
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs datanode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_DATANODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
Starting secondary namenodes [host1-virtual-machine]
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs secondarynamenode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
2020-02-12 14:40:27,093 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
ERROR: Attempting to operate on yarn resourcemanager as root
ERROR: but there is no YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER defined. Aborting operation.
Starting nodemanagers
ERROR: Attempting to operate on yarn nodemanager as root
ERROR: but there is no YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER defined. Aborting operation.
```

In host1 user:

```
host1@host1-virtual-machine:~/usr/hadoop-3.2.1$ sbin/start-all.sh
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as host1 in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: host1@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: host1@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [host1-virtual-machine]
host1-virtual-machine: host1@host1-virtual-machine: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: host1@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up passwordless connection between  nodes. This link might help
http://mynotesonhadoop.blogspot.com/2017/07/configuring-passwordless-ssh-from.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you!! After your two answers, I solve the two problems，the different users and passwordless connection.

Comment: If it solved for query,you could accept my solution